# Equivalent encryption logic for Yii generatePasswordHash?

Tags: java, android, yii, cryptography

I have php(Yii) api, which requires encrypted password(used function generatePasswordHash($password)). how to encrypt password in java which matched with generatePasswordHash($password).

Answer (score 0):

All the indications in the Yii documentation seem to point to the **bcrypt** password hashing algorithm. The `cost` parameter undoubtedly points to the cost factor required for bcrypt and there is a direct mention of the Blowfish algorithm used within bcrypt in the [description of the `cost` parameter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#generatePasswordHash()-detail). Finally it points to PHP's `password-hash` function which has bcrypt as initial constant.

That bcrypt is used can be further verified by looking at the output of `generatePasswordHash` of course.

So it comes down to finding a Java bcrypt implementation that also uses the `$2y` output format. Some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38597604/589259)